# getting a random product in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

## /products/index.html.erb

```
<div class="hide-for-small panel">
  <h3>Sidebar</h3>
  <h5 class="subheader">Feature Product</h5>
    <% Product.random do | product | %>
     <%= image_tag(Product.image_url) %> 
     <h5><%= link_to Product.title, product %></h5>
     <p><%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(:product_id => product) %></p>
    <% end %>               
</div>
```

## /models/product.rb

```
def Product.random
 self.limit(1).offset(rand(self.count)).first 
end
```

Trying to pull a random product using Postgres. The query comes through in the console but I get no view results in the index.

Any solutions or different ways of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole issue is you're passing a block to a method that doesn't take a block, so its silently ignored, and never executed, so the *other* problems you have don't come up.

All of your code sits inside a block which you're passing to `Product.random` via `Product.random do |product|`. That should be `product = Product.random` with no `do/end` block.

Once you've done this, you'll start seeing more errors as you're using `Product.title` instead of `product.title` etc.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your product in your image_tag and link are incorrectly referencing the model and not the random one.

Try changing these:

```
  <%= image_tag(product.image_url) %> 
 <h5><%= link_to product.title, product %></h5>
```

Comment: Changing those are doing the same thing. No Errors, No View Results, but it is loading in the console still.

Comment: In your console how many results do you get for Product.random? It seems like you can't iterate over in your do loop because it's only getting one?

Comment: The results from the console are Product Load (0.0ms) SELECT "products".* FROM "products" ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1

Comment: It will always return one result, so calling try calling this in your console (I don't think this loop works):

`Product.random do | product |`
  `puts product.title`
`end` 
(Just to verify my thought that the loop doesn't actually do anything)

Comment: Now that is giving me results, and a different product id each time.

Comment: @musicnerd47 basically answered what I was thinking next.

Comment: And @meagar made the same point about the loop. You don't need a loop to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

You should really generate the random product in your controller and access an instance variable in your view.

Something like:
controller's index action:

```
@random_product = Product.random
```

view:

```
<%= image_tag(@random_product.image_url) %>
```

etc. 
You should never access the model directly from the view.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're mixing up class methods with instance methods. Try making the view:

```
<div class="hide-for-small panel">
  <h3>Sidebar</h3>
  <h5 class="subheader">Feature Product</h5>
  <%= image_tag(@product.image_url) %> 
  <h5><%= link_to @product.title, @product %></h5>
  <p><%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(:product_id => @product.id) %></p>
</div>
```

Class methods (`Product.random`) are defined when you don't need a specific one. So `product.title` if for a specific product.

Second of all, in your controller for this action, you'll need to define the `@product` instance variable as `@product = Product.random`. And then you can use that in the view.

Third of all, getting a random record could be simplified to:

```
Product.order("RANDOM()").first
```

So your model code would look like:

```
def self.random
  Product.order("RANDOM()").first 
end
```